# If i deleted something from iPad notes how can I get it back?

Tags: macos

If I deleted something from iPad  notes can I get it back somehow?

Answer (score 3):

If you have synced your notes with an iCloud account and your iPad is not connected to the internet you have a chance to access your notes at [iCloud.com](http://icloud.com).
If your iCloud account is set with other devices like iPhone, Mac, and even Windows with iCloud application installed you have more chances to recover your note before connecting them to the internet.